# If a exists pick a else pick b power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have forecast and budget values for the year, and a new forecast is created every quarter. I need PowerBI to pick up the Metric Value (can be Budget, Q1F, Q2F and Q3F) for a given date based on data availability.

Example - If for a given date, data for Q3F is available, pick Q3F, else pick Q2F else Q1F else budget.

This is what my data looks like:

```
Date      Metric   Value
1/1/11    Budget   1.1
1/1/11    Q3F      1.2
1/1/11    Q2F      1.3
```

In this case the function should pick up Q3F since it's available.

Comment: Do you want to have it in M or in DAX?

Comment: Preferably DAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this would be by using both a `SUMX` and a `SWITCH` Statements.

To start with assign a constant to your forecasts, e.g. budget = 1, Q1F = 2 and so on as a column on your data. The idea more recent forecast will have a higher number, it will be used in the switch statement late.  I am going to refer to it as forecast_ID in this example.

I am also assuming you have a calendar table, also that your forecasts are entered in entirely for the business and not in waves.  E.g. Category A is still on budget, Category B is an updated forecast.

The idea of below, is that the SUMX iterates though each quarter that you are looking at, e.g. 2018 would run Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 separately.

Within the context of each quarter, it is getting the MAX of your forecast IDs, which is then used in the switch to select the most recent forecast.

```
Measure :=
SUMX (
    VALUES ( Calendar[Quarter] ),
    SWITCH (
        MAX ( table1[forecast_ID] ),
        1, CALCULATE ( SUM ( table1[value] ), table1[Metric] = "Budget" ),
        2, CALCULATE ( SUM ( table1[value] ), table1[Metric] = "Q1F" )
    )
)
```

You could also then do something like `MAX ( table1[forecast_ID] - 1)` for finding the previous forecast dynamically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Is there a way we can add the Quarter values to the legend to the graph we build from this?

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to pull the most recent value then you can use **LASTNONBLANK**

As Marcus mentioned, the first step is to create a constant for your forecasts. I set up a separate table for this example.

[image]

Then you can create a relationship between the two tables based on **Metric**. Add a calculated column to your original table

```
MetricConstant = RELATED(Table2[Constant])
```

Now create a measure to pull the most recent value within each date period

```
Measure =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( Table1[Date] ),
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[Value] ), LASTNONBLANK ( Table1[MetricConstant], 1 ) )
)
```

Now when you pull in the **Date** and the **Measure** it will only show you the most recent available

[image]

EDIT-Updated based on comments. If you want to view which **Metric** is being used you need another measure

```
MetricMeasure = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Metric]),LASTNONBLANK(Table1[MetricConstant],1))
```

You could create an area chart based on that, and add this to the tooltip. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks Stu. I need to create an area chart from this and need to add the Metric name as the legend. Is there a way to do that? Every time i add metric to the table, the granularity changes.

Comment: You would need a separate measure to pull out which metric it is using. I edited my answer. You could add it as a tooltip but I'm not sure you could actually add it as a legend. It would just show "MetricMeasure" and you would have to hover over on the area chart to see which one it was